# Unexpected performance boost after adding JOIN and ORDER BY to query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

I have the following **People** table:

```
| Id | FirstName | Children |
|----|-----------|----------|
|  1 |      mark |        4 |
|  2 |      paul |        0 |
|  3 |      mike |        3 |
```

Note I have an non-unique index in **FirstName** and another one in **Children**.

I need to get the top 10000 first names and the children amount of every person that has any children. So I decided to go for this solution:

```
SELECT firstName, children FROM people
WHERE children > 0
ORDER BY children DESC
LIMIT 0, 10000
```

The thing is that it takes 4 seconds to return the results from a table with 2.6 million records. This is the explain:

```
| ID | SELECT_TYPE | TABLE  | TYPE  | POSSIBLE_KEYS | KEY      | KEY_LEN | REF    |       ROWS | EXTRA       |
|----|-------------|--------|-------|---------------|----------|---------|--------|------------|-------------|
|  1 |      SIMPLE | people | range | children      | children |       4 | (null) |    2677610 | Using where |
```

As I see it, the **range** is telling me the index is being scanned and compared to a value (in this case this is the **children > 0**). I'd say that should be fast enough. Then, my guess is that after getting all those matching index elements, the DBMS fetches the **firstName** from the table by internally joining the values in the index with the ones in the table.

If I translate the previous paragraph into SQL I would get something like this:

```
SELECT firstName, children FROM people
JOIN (
    SELECT id FROM people
    WHERE children > 0
    ORDER BY children DESC
    LIMIT 0, 10000
) s
ON people.id = s.id
ORDER BY children DESC
```

The explain for the previous SQL statement is:

```
| ID | SELECT_TYPE | TABLE      | TYPE   | POSSIBLE_KEYS | KEY      | KEY_LEN | REF    |    ROWS | EXTRA                           |
|----|-------------|------------|--------|---------------|----------|---------|--------|---------|---------------------------------|
|  1 |     PRIMARY | <derived2> | ALL    | (null)        | (null)   |  (null) | (null) |   10000 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 |     PRIMARY | p          | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  |       4 | s.id   |       1 |                                 |
|  2 |     DERIVED | people     | range  | children      | children |       4 | (null) | 2687462 | Using where; Using index        |
```

To my surprise, this query performs a few times **faster** than the first one. However, the more I increment the **LIMIT X** the bigger this difference becomes (EG: For **LIMIT 1000000, 10000** the second query is still under 1 second and the first one exceeds 20 seconds). This leads me to the following questions:

1. In what way is MySQL handling the first query different from the second?
2. Is there any way to hint MySQL to execute the first query the way it executes the second?
3. Is it fair to say that the lesson learned from this is that whenever I want to fetch a value that is not part of the index being used, the double order by and join is the right way to go?

Additional notes:

- [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4859e4/1) (if it makes any difference)
- Note I'm running the queries with **SQL_NO_CACHE**
- MySQL version: 5.5.37

Comment: Use index hint `SELECT * FROM table1 USE INDEX (col1_index) WHERE col1=1;` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-hints.html for the first query

Comment: Actually, I have already tried a similar one by forcing it to go for the primary key for JOIN and for the children index for the ORDER BY. But I had no luck either. I also tried the specific one you mentioned and I didn't have any luck either.

Comment: try updating your statistics using [Analyze Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html) and running the 1st query again

Comment: Read this guy's blog http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/ He suggests some ways to improve the performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I've found this issue detailed in the book *High Performance MySQL - B. Schwartz*.

In page 193 there are some examples of high offset (i.e. **LIMIT 1000000, 10**) queries and some alternatives to improve them. After that I quote:

> Another good strategy for optimizing such queries is to use a deferred join, which again is our term for using a covering index to retrieve just the primary key columns of the rows you’ll eventually retrieve. You can then join this back to the table to retrieve all desired columns. This helps minimize the amount of work MySQL must do gathering data that it will only throw away. Here’s an example that requires an index on (sex, rating) to work efficiently:
>
> ```
> SELECT <cols> FROM profiles INNER JOIN (
>     SELECT <primary key cols> FROM profiles
>     WHERE x.sex='M' ORDER BY rating LIMIT 100000, 10
> ) AS x USING(<primary key cols>);
> ```

So it seems the key factor is to use the (existing) primary key as a covering index for the inner query.

So answering my own questions:

1. In what way is MySQL handling the first query different from the second?

   It seems the first one is fetching more than just the primary keys for all rows before the offset.
2. Is there any way to hint MySQL to execute the first query the way it executes the second?

   Apparently not. You will have to rewrite the whole query again.
3. Is it fair to say that the lesson learned from this is that whenever I want to fetch a value that is not part of the index being used, the double order by and join is the right way to go?

   So it seems. However, for small offsets, using the deferred join might not result in a performance boost.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that you can fix the performance of the first query by having an index on `children, firstname`.  This is a covering index for the query, so it should eliminate accesses to the data pages.

The first execution plan says that the index is being used for the `where`.  The `limit` is applied last, so it seems that it is getting the `firstname` for *all* the rows before the `limit` is applied.  That seems weird, but it is consistent with the performance you are seeing.

In the second version, 10000 ids are being read.  Assuming they are primary keys, then the data page look ups should be quite fast -- and controlled explicitly by the limit.  This may suggest why this version is faster, although it seems like a bit of a mystery.  Mostly, though, I would expect the index on `children, firstname` to improve the first version of the query.

Comment: I agree on all these points. The covering index should be quite fast. However, the children field is very dynamic so the performance hit will be at insert/update time. Anyway, I wouldn't add an index to make the first query work faster if I already have a faster query without the index. I also agree on `firstname` being fetched for all rows before the limit, which is the main issue: If it is really using the index for the `where` then why would it go to the table to fetch values (`firstnames`) that are out of the (`children`) limit range? Smells like a poor implementation of the limit clause.

Comment: @MostyMostacho . . . The `limit` clause is applied after everything else, including the `order by`.  It *seems* like a poor choice of methodology for the ordering when there are additional columns.  In other words, it seems like it is ordering *after* picking up the extra columns rather than before.  That makes sense as a general approach (because an extra column could be used in the `order by`).  But an easy optimization when there is an index.